# React reusable function that sets useContext

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, use-state, use-context

My current function handleLogin() takes care of calling to an API that sets the state of loggedIn to true inside the then() block like so.

```
function handleLogin() {
if(username.length && password.length) {
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `apiurl...`,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        
    }) 
    }).then((response) => {
        setResponse()
        setLoggedIn(true)
        setLogMsg(response.data.data)
        console.log(response.data.data)
    }, (error) => {
    console.log(error) 
    })
}
else {
  alert(`Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe n'est pas valide`)
}
```

}

This works fine. But i would like to abstract this function and use it inside a reusable component. The problem is i cannot use react's context api inside a non-react component, and so i cannot set the context/state accross my app.

When i try to use this function inside its own component i get the error:
"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

Are there any solutions to this problem?